# Json to Sql translation

Tags: php, sql, json

I'm looking for library for PHP that can translate json to sql. 
That is, based on some definition, or schema, it should generate insert/update statements.

Anyone know of such library? I asked few search engines and nothing pops out.

Example:

JSON

```
{
    "person_id": 1,
    "name": "John Doe",

    "roles": ["admin","editor","regular_user"],

    "friends": 
    [
        {"person_id": 10, "name": "Johny Walker", "is_best_friend": true},
        {...} // more friends
    ]
}
```

Table structure:

```
Persons: person_id (int), name (text)
Roles: person_id (int), role (text)
Friends: person_id (int), is_best_friend (bool)
```

This is just example.

What I have in mind is XSLT-like transformation. I understand that such system will be quite complex, but this simple example can be translated without problems.

I was thinking of implementing it myself, but I'm lazy, so asking first.

Advanced JSON stuff, like referencing, can also be implemented as it fits nicely into relational tables (with possible limitations).

Comment: What? Can you update the question and add some text? Do you speek of model to model transformation?

Comment: I realize this isn't really addressing your question but have you considered a document-oriented database like [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/)?

Comment: @Mike Steinert - yes, it doesn't go well with what I'm doing.

Answer (score 2):

SQL data structure is plain and has strict "hard-coded" structure, but JSON can store objects, wich are are inherited one into another. I do not think, that such tool exist. Even id does, it will have a lot of limitations.

Comment: This is a simple script that could map any array to a series of INPUT statements, not multi table support, no schema mapping.

Answer (score 0):

What you really need to search for is a [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-Relational_Mapping).

Typical programming constructs differ greatly from the way sql works, this is called [Object-relational impedance mismatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_impedance_mismatch). Trying to map or transform a object or array structure to a database schema is no trivial task as it requires knowledge about two data structures and a ruleset about every value.

Comment: Thanks, i'm currently using doctrine, don't like it, so researching some crazy ideas.

Comment: I'm using Doctrine too, and I get you point ;). But I can't imagine anything else that would be broad enough to become a framework and not  become a total mess.